# "With" usage in adverbial

Tags: perfect-constructions, participles

"With" is a preposition which can be followed with present participle or past participle like:

1) He sat there with his eyes closed.

2) He fell asleep with the lamp burning.

But can I say "He goes to sleep with the task having been finished." to imply a sense of present perfect? Is it correct in grammar? If not, how English native speaker uses adverbial to indicate the sense of present perfect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**with** can be used that way, it is grammatical. We could use the word **now** to express the same idea:

> He falls asleep, (with) the task having been finished.
>
> He falls asleep, (with) the task now finished.

**now** would be understood to refer to the moment of his falling asleep. The present perfect there is also taking the moment of his falling asleep as its present reference point.